# Assigning Array to a Struct value in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

For a homework assignment, we are working on CSV parser.  I'm trying to get things working, but I've run into an issue.  I can't seem to assign a value to "field" value in the struct.  In the code they provided they have:

```
typedef char f_string[MAX_CHARS+1] ;    /* string for each field */

    typedef struct {
        int nfields;                        /* 0 => end of file */
        f_string field[MAX_FIELDS];         /* array of strings for fields */
    } csv_line ;
```

With the above constants defined at 20 and 15.  Looking at what they have, the struct holds and int, and it holds an array that should be populated with the f_string typedef they defined earlier.  Alright, cool.  I tried to do it this way:

```
f_string test = "Hello, Bob";
f_string testAgain = "this is dumb, k?";
f_string anArray[MAX_FIELDS] = {*test, *testAgain};

csv_line aLine;
aLine.nfields = 3;
aLine.field = *anArray;
```

When I make "anArray", if I don't have the dereferences to test and testAgain, I get warnings about making integers to pointers without a cast.  So I leave them in.  But the line:

```
aLine.field = *anArray;
```

Returns the error: "csv.c:87: error: incompatible types in assignment" with or without the pointer there... so I'm not sure how I should be assigning that variable?  Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't assign to an array using `=`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744536/c-array-declaration-and-assignment) for a more detailed explanation.

You'll need to copy each string using the [`strcpy`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcpy.html) (or the safer [`strncpy`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncpy.html)) function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < aLine.nfields; ++i)
{
  strncpy(aLine.field[i], anArray[i], MAX_CHARS);
}
```

Also, the test code you provide isn't going to do what you expect.

```
f_string test = "Hello, Bob";
f_string testAgain = "this is dumb, k?";
f_string anArray[MAX_FIELDS] = {*test, *testAgain};
```

This will copy the first *character* of `test` and `testAgain`.  You need to do something like:

```
f_string test = "Hello, Bob";
f_string testAgain = "this is dumb, k?";
f_string anArray[MAX_FIELDS];
strcpy(anArray[0], test);
strcpy(anArray[1], testAgain);
```

Or just:

```
f_string anArray[MAX_FIELDS] = {"Hello, Bob", "this is dumb, k"};
```

Comment: Note that this won't necessarily null-terminate the string unless the array already has an `'\0'` at `aLine.field[i][MAX_CHARS]`.

Comment: I realized that my code above wasn't working, and that with your code, I would have to strcpy them in.  Thank you!