# Put array variable in multidimensional array

Tags: c, arduino

I want the following

```
int ring1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int ring2[5] = {6,7,8,9,10};
int ring3[5] = {11,12,13,14,15};
int rings[3][5] = {ring1, ring2, ring3};
```

But I get an error on the last line:

> Array Must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer.

Comment: Time to open up your text-book on the chapters on *pointers*.

Comment: Arrays cannot be copied by assignment. They can be copied with `memcpy` or element by element in a loop. You could make `rings` into an array of pointers, e.g. `int *rings[3] = {ring1, ring2, ring3};` but note that any changes to `ring1[i]` will also change `rings[0][i]` and vice versa. Likewise for `ring2` and `ring3`.

Comment: dupe of [C array declaration and assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744536/c-array-declaration-and-assignment), etc.

Comment: The error is kind of misleading , are you compiling using `C++` compiler?

Comment: @IrAM Arduino is quasi-C++, so kinda yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C` name of the array indicates the base address of the array, so all of your `ring1`, `ring2` and `ring3` gives the address of their starting element (i.e 0th).

Similarly `rings` is also an array (Its a 2 Dimensional array).

We cannot store  address in arrays, for that will have to use pointers.

So we have to use below way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ring1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int ring2[5] = {6,7,8,9,10};
    int ring3[5] = {11,12,13,14,15};
    //int rings[3][5] = {{ring1}, {ring2}, {ring3}};
    int *rings[3] = {ring1, ring2, ring3};
    
    printf("ring1 = %p and rings[0] =%p\n", ring1, rings[0]);
    printf("ring2 = %p and rings[1] =%p\n", ring1, rings[1]);
    printf("ring3 = %p and rings[2] =%p\n", ring1, rings[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this loses the size info for the 'nested' arrays, and other issues from using pointers. A less direct but more correct fix would be to iterate and assign the sub-arrays IMO